# Why is my difference function not producing the actual difference and giving back zero?

Tags: c

So I am new to C and trying to prove Stirlings approximation. The natural_log and approximation function does work from what I have tested. And right now I am learning on how to parse those arrays into the difference function. I looked at over code online and it seems that I am using the syntax correctly but it doesn't give me the result I wanted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ELEMENTS 100

void natural_log ();
/* Obtain the natural log of 0 to 100 and then store each value in an array */
void approximation ();
/* Use the sterling approximation caluculate the numbers from 0 - 100 and  then store it in an array */
double * difference ();
/* Calculate the difference between the arrays */
double * percentage ();
/* Calculate the percentage of the difference and return the array */

int main () {
   natural_log ();
   approximation ();
   difference ();
   return 0;
}

void natural_log () {

    static double natural_array[ELEMENTS]; /* set up the array */
    int i, j; /* set up the integer to increase the array by a value */


    natural_array[0] = 0.0; /* set up the first value in the array */
    natural_array[1] = log(1.0);

    double x;
    x = natural_array [1];
    for (i = 2; i <=100; i++) { /* set up the for loop to increment the i  */
        natural_array[i] = x + log(1 + i);
        x = natural_array[i];
    /*    printf ("Element[%d] = %f\n", i, x); Check */
     }
}

void approximation () {

    static double approximation_array[ELEMENTS]; /* set up the array */
    int i;  /* set up the integer to increase the array by a value */

    for (i = 0; i <=100; i++) {
        approximation_array[i] = (i) * log(i) - (i);
       /*  printf ("Elements[%d] = %f\n", i, approximation_array[i]); Check   */
    }
}
double * difference (double * natural_array, double * approximation_array)   {

    static double difference_array[ELEMENTS];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        difference_array[i] = (natural_array[i] - approximation_array[i]);
        printf ("Elements[%d] = %f\n", i, difference_array[i]);
    }
    return difference_array;
}
```

So when I run the program it produces this output

```
Element[0] = 0.0000
Element[1] = 0.0000
Element[2] = 0.0000
....
....
Element[100] = 0.0000
```

I know there are differences in the natural log and the approximation when I ran the check lines for the print function but it doesn't seem to be getting those numbers any ideas?

Comment: look at call to difference(). you don't pass any arguments...

Comment: This loop: `for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {` invokes undefined behaviour, so the output is correct.  When you invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen.  (It should be: `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {`.)  Also, note that none of the function declarations at the top is a prototype; you're wasting your compiler's abilities that would help you avoid problems if you declared the functions with prototypes.  Add the parameters (and `void` when there are no parameters) so the compiler can spot the problem @MitchWheat pointed out.

Comment: All three of your functions return results; you discard them.

Comment: Where is natural_array[] and aproximation_array[] coming from?

Comment: @MitchWheat So I am a little confused here I call the two parameters when I write the difference function. So when I run it in main it should have those parameters set right? If I do add in those variables it gives me back errors.

Comment: @GRC they are the arrays that come from the other functions natural_log and the approximation function.

Comment: @SulimanSharif you never return those arrays from the functions or anything. arrays don't magically move around and appear where you want them.

Comment: suggest enabling all warnings when compiling.  (there are several warnings)  then fix the warnings (don't mask them) then is should be obvious that the first two sub functions need to return a pointer to their static array, so main() can pass those pointers to the third sub function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code causes undefined behaviour by calling a function with the wrong number of arguments.

For example, `double * difference (double * natural_array, double * approximation_array)` must be called with two arguments. But you write:

```
difference();
```

in `main`.  Normally compilers would diagnose this and print an error message, however you disabled that feature by writing the non-prototype declaration `double * difference ();`.

The first thing you should do is remove all of the non-prototype declarations. Either use prototypes (e.g. `double * difference (double *, double *);`), or place the function bodies in a different order so that no forward declaration is necessary.

Functions that take no arguments should have the parameter list `(void)` , not `()`.

After that you will need to re-design your function arguments and return values so that the arrays you need are available. For example, the `natural_log()` and `approximation()` functions work on arrays which are contained inside those functions and you never expose those arrays outside of the function.  Instead you need to have `difference` work on those arrays.